# How do I install mono's System.Windows.Forms on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, software-installation, mono

I haven't found any concise explanation of this.

Comment: What are the other Mono dependencies besides mono-runtime and libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil required to run C# Windows Forms applications on Ubuntu Linux 16.04? Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So you're looking for a package containing a file called `System.Windows.Forms.dll`. You can search:

- on your machine: `apt-file search System.Windows.Forms.dll` (the [`apt-file` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/apt-file) must be installed)
- online: at [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/#search_contents).

Both methods lead you to (as of Ubuntu 14.04):

- [`libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil) and
- [`libmono-winforms2.0-cil`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libmono-winforms2.0-cil).

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil
```

Comment: What are the other Mono dependencies besides mono-runtime and libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil required to run C# Windows Forms applications on Ubuntu Linux 16.04? Thank you.

Comment: +1 for teaching me how to fish.

Answer (score 2):

Open Synaptic and search for System.Windows.Forms and select libmono-winforms2.0-cil or libmono-winforms1.0-cil and then apply.

(optional) You might need to install System.Runtime package as well. just search for that and install libmono-system-runtime2.0-cil or libmono-system-runtime1.0-cil

Answer (score 1):

Found it via [this link](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/dotnet/print.htm?TYPE=story&AT=339279567-339028399t-320002019c):

```
% apt-get install libmono-winforms1.0-cil libmono-winforms2.0-cil
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the references menu, Typing in the left upper size of MonoDevelop's GUI the Word Reference. It'll open a window. There you'll be able to enable the reference `System.Windows.Forms`. As it's enabled, you'll be able to declare in your code:

```
Using System.Windows.Forms;
```

and use it as well. This answer assumes that you've done all the previous in this page.